# Perform action onclick outside of object

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementsbyclassname

I'm attempting to create a javascript where when you click anywhere on the screen but on an object, it does a bit of code. (To close a dialogue box, remove nighttime mode, etc.)

```
//Imagine some CSS declaring that FPAGE takes up 100% of the screen.
<div id="FPAGE" onclick="return outClick();">
    <script>
        function outClick() {
            var o=document.getElementsByClassName('objects');
            //What now?
        }
    </script>
    <center>
        <object class="objects" width="500px" height="500px"></object>
        <br />
        <object class="objects" width="500px" height="500px"></object>
    </center>
</div>
```

I'm really unsure what I should be doing. I have thought of some sudo code, but I don't know if this can be done in javascript.

```
var o=document.getElementsByClassName('objects');
//What now?
if (onclick!=o) {
    //insert code here
}
```

**SOLUTION:** (Thanks to David)

```
<script>
document.onclick = function(e) {
    var o=document.getElementsByClassName('objects');
    if ( e.target.nodeName != 'o' ) {
        //Code here!
    }
};
</script>
<center>
    <object class="objects" width="500px" height="500px"></object>
    <br />
    <object class="objects" width="500px" height="500px"></object>
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I'm really unsure what I should be doing"_ javascript tutorials, not asking questions.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your expected result? Please explain vividly.

Comment: Essentially a night time mode for a stream, where the background becomes black. But once you've clicked anywhere but on the streams, it becomes daytime again.

Comment: And the streams I guess are the objects?

Comment: correct, the streams are the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a click event on the entire page, then check whether the *target* of that click was the object (or perhaps a descendant of that object). Something like this:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
    if ( e.target.nodeName != 'OBJECT' ) {
        // the click happened on a non-object (probably "outside")
    }
};
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/elikum/1

Remember that javascript events are difficult to normalize in legacy browsers, so depending on the target audience you might consider a library like jQuery to make event handling easier.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. Will up vote once I get some reputation.

Answer (score 0):

So you got an answer that you're looking for, great.

By the way;

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a "NodeList" or "HTMLCollection"(ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName).

So you need `for-next` method to attach event to nodes.

```
// i.e
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('objects'), 
    el, i;
for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    el = els[i];
    el.onclick = function() {
    // ...
}

// or
while (el = els[i++]) {
    el.onclick = // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Working off of your example, you just need to add a check to see what element was actually clicked by checking the target property of the event.  You don't really need the 'objects' class, you could instead modify it to check the tagName as a couple other folks did in their answers. The classname check I added definitely isn't ideal because it would pass for even if you had a class longer class name that happened to contain the word 'objects'.  You could use a library like jQuery to make your life easier.

Try this, drop this html in a file and load it up in a browser.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function outClick(event) {
                    if(event.target.className.indexOf('objects') > -1) {
                    alert("is object");
                } else {
                    alert("not object");
                }
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            html,body,#FPAGE { height:100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="FPAGE" onclick="outClick(event)">
            <center>
                <object class="objects" width="500px" height="500px">OBJECT</object>
                <br />
                <object class="objects" width="500px" height="500px">OBJECT2</object>
            </center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be cleaner to add event handlers for the objects where you don't want to handle clicks, doing event.stopPropgation (or, if you already have event handlers for the objects, just add event.stopPropagation to them), then add the event handler for the entire page.

```
var objects=document.GetObjectsByClassName('objects');
for (var i=0, len=objects.length; i<len; i++) {
    objects[i].addEventListener("click",function(event){event.stopPropagation();});
}
document.addEventListener("click",...)
```

This approach will be more robust as your application evolves, and you add additional items on which you don't to handle the click--compared to building a monster IF statement in the document event handler, you can specify the behavior (suppress click or not) at the individual element level.